# Add multiple images to a tweet with python and twitterApi?

Tags: python, twitter, tweets

Hi I've been trying to add four images to a tweet using the twitterAPI module in python - This code below unfortunately only renders one of the images from data in the tweet. Can someone point me in the right direction to attach four images to the tweet? My code is below (minus the imports, and secret keys)

```
api = TwitterAPI(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

output_message = "Four Cool Images:"
data = ""
for x in range(0, 4):`enter code here`
   filename = "/temp/images/image" + x + ".jpg"   # file name of image.
    file = open(filename, 'rb') 
    stream = file.read()
    data = data + stream

r = api.request('statuses/update_with_media', {'status':output_message}, {'media[]':data})
print(r.status_code)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'statuses/update_with_media' is deprecated. Below is the preferred method.

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

TWEET_TEXT = 'some tweet text'
IMAGE_PATH = './some_image.png'

api = TwitterAPI(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

# STEP 1 - upload image
file = open(IMAGE_PATH, 'rb')
data = file.read()
r = api.request('media/upload', None, {'media': data})
print('UPLOAD MEDIA SUCCESS' if r.status_code == 200 else 'UPLOAD MEDIA FAILURE')

# STEP 2 - post tweet with a reference to uploaded image
if r.status_code == 200:
    media_id = r.json()['media_id']
    r = api.request('statuses/update', {'status':TWEET_TEXT, 'media_ids':media_id})
    print('UPDATE STATUS SUCCESS' if r.status_code == 200 else 'UPDATE STATUS FAILURE')
```

Comment: this made it clear - thank you. I had to upgrade TwitterAPI to newest version and just loop thru 4 images , retreive the media_ids and put them in a string to send all four images. THank you!

Answer (score 3):

The parameter list `media_ids` must be a string with `media_ids` separated with commas.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue so i modified a bit the code up there and it works perfectly (excuse me if it's not very clear...) My images are just named 1.jpg, 2.jpg ...

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

api = TwitterAPI(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
media_ids = ''

for i in range(2): #Set 1 to 4 images (exemple with 2)
    TWEET_TEXT = 'some tweet text'
    IMAGE_PATH = f'{i}.jpg'
    file = open(IMAGE_PATH, 'rb')
    data = file.read()
    r = api.request('media/upload', None, {'media': data})
    print('UPLOAD MEDIA SUCCESS' if r.status_code == 200 else 'UPLOAD MEDIA FAILURE')


    if r.status_code == 200:
        if i == 0:
            media_ids += str(r.json()['media_id'])
        else:
            media_ids = media_ids + ',' + str(r.json()['media_id'])

#POST IMAGES
r = api.request('statuses/update', {'status':TWEET_TEXT, 'media_ids':media_ids})
print('UPDATE STATUS SUCCESS' if r.status_code == 200 else 'UPDATE STATUS FAILURE')
```